# Performing group by on tombstone values

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

What will happen when performing a groupby on a ktable which contains tombstone values? 
Seems that the groupby is not being evaluated, but will the tombstone be forwarded just like filter method does?

Answer (score 5):

A KTable cannot "contain" a tombstone because it would be interpreted as a delete for the corresponding key.

However, if you have a `KTable#groupBy()` and something gets deleted in the upstream `KTable`, the groupBy/aggregate is updated such that the old value is removed from the aggregation result.

Example: Upstream `KTable` with 3 entries: `<k1,a>, <k2,b>, <k3, a>` and you group-by the value and do a count. The result `KTable` would contain: `<a, 2>, <b, 1>`.

If you get a tombstone `<k1, null>` for the upstream `KTable` the result `KTable` will be updated to `<a, 1>, <b, 1>`.

Comment: This answer is very helpful. In case it helps someone else, it took me a while to reproduce this behavior because I specified an attribute in the value of the record as the timestamp. When doing that I had to produce a record that included the key and the timestamp in the value, but leave the attributes used in the group by as null.
Below is the example table create that required timestamp in tombstone.
CREATE TABLE example (
  ky String PRIMARY KEY,
  eventTimestamp Timestamp
) WITH (
  kafka_topic = 'example',
  value_format = 'json',
  timestamp='eventTimestamp'
);

Comment: Yeah, the answer is tailored to KafkaStream, not ksqlDB, and assumes that the timestamp is taken from the record timestamp field, not from the value.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Would directly sending to the repartition topic created by groupBy work OK? In the above example that would be sending <a, null>? My tests are throwing a:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.ChangedDeserializer.deserialize(ChangedDeserializer.java:49)`

Comment: You should not write anything into the repartition topic from "outside" (ie, via some producer). -- Repartition topics are considered internal and as you can observe, you break it and it crashes.